# Can the compiler optimize away method call?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    int calculate( int arg1 ) const;
    void side_effect( int arg) const;
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
{
    MyClass m;
    m.calculate( 100 );
    m.side_effect( 100 );
}
```

Is the compiler free skip the `m.calculate( )` call - since I do not hold on to the return value? For the `side_effect( )`method I really hope the compiler can not skip the call - even though the method is marked `const`?

EDIT: The reason I ask this question is that my `calculate( )` function has a side effect, but through the use of `mutable` it is marked as `const`. Now in the normal case I want to hold on to the return value, and the whole problem is moot - but in the case illustrated above I am only interested in being certain that the side effect has been invoked (Yes - I know it is not pretty ...). Reading the answers/comments I get the feeling you think compiler can deduce whether a method has side effects; that was surprising to me?

Comment: The result must be as-if the function was called. If it has no effect, how can you tell the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what `m.calculate()` does.

If it only retrieves values and then throws them away then, indeed, there is nothing useful for your computer to do here and your finished program may very well not even make the call.

However, the extent to which compilers can perform optimisations is limited by the visibility of the function's definition, among other things.

The `const` has nothing to do with it. So, if `m.side_effect()` has side effects, it cannot be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The compile will optimize away any code that has no effect at runtime, if it can tell that at compile time, e.g. branches that are never called and values that are never used. Const data and objects can be handy here since their value is known at compile time. Putting const on a method itself won't change that: it just means that you know this method won't change it's object. The object itself is still non-const, so even though the method is const, the compile doesn't 100% know what the data values could be at the time that method runs. There's still the possibility that a non-const method changed the object at some point.

Additionally, methods declared in a class like that are inline: they will be replaced by the code themselves instead of a function call. Whatever "action" the side_effect method does will be directly written into the code in place of the function call itself. The entire thing won't be optimized away unless it actually does nothing, which shouldn't be a problem.

BTW. A const method can still affect related objects, e.g. accessing data through a pointer inside the class, it can freely change the data that's pointed to, but can't change the address of the pointer itself.

Comment: "they will be replaced by the code themselves instead of a function call". They **might** be replaced by the code. No compiler I heard of will for sure inline the `inline` methods. It will decide what is better during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's distinguish the 'can and 'should' to be more presize.
With regards to 'can', the ability of the compiller to optimize some cetain code constructions depends on the code design and how "smart" the compiler is. As more hints the compiler has, as more tightly it can optimize something.

In your case, if the functions `side_effect` and `calculate` are dummy and don't do anything (and `calculate` returns a statically hardcoded value), they can be optimized out. Besides that, their parameters can also be optimized (please don't mix this case with 'should') at the place they are declared and defined. But for this reason (especially if some simple compiller is used) you probably need to give more hints about the parameters declaring them as const references to int rather to pass them by value.

In this case, your code

```
MyClass m;
m.calculate( 100 );
m.side_effect( 100 );
```

won't produce any instruction to the executable neither for the functions, nor for their parameters.

Also, giving consts, you won't force the compiller to optimize some code, but you help the compiler to recognize that the code can be optimized when it should be optimized.